# Isolated Azure Function Isolated model generated by Azure function core Tools 4.0.5198 does not work

Tags: .net-7.0, azure-functions-core-tools, azure-functions-isolated

I used Azure function core tools (version 4.0.5198) to created an isolated function as commands below:

> func init LocalFunctionProj --worker-runtime dotnet-isolated
> --target-framework net7.0
>
> cd ./LocalFunctionProj
>
> func new --name HttpExample --template "HTTP trigger" --authlevel
> "anonymous"

The project and function code were generated and built successfully, but when I run with command

> func start

then it said that

> "No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods
> public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage,
> ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration
> method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g.
> builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(),
> builder.AddTimers(), etc.)."

Can you please share your solution if possible please.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide your code in the question?

Comment: Thanks Darasi Kamali, it's a very default code generated by azure function core tool, I did not modify anything

Answer (score 0):

I've found reason why, because of the nuget package cache from this
%userprofile%.nuget\packages
Clean up everything related to Worker Functions will make it work.